# rails 3.1 has_many problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

i had updated my project in a few days. but now i have a question on that. there is my example code in rails 3.1 has_many association.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ...
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

in my console ,i use these test sentences.

```
c.addresses.new
 => #<CustomerAddress id: nil, customer_id: 6, address2: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :013 > c.addresses
 => [#<Address id: 7, customer_id: 6 address2: nil>, #<Address id: nil, customer_id: 6, address2: nil]
```

i want c.addresses not include the last result.

Answer (score 1):

try `c.addresses.reload`, it reloads rows from db

Answer (score 0):

try

```
c.addresses.all
```

This will actually query the database instead of looking at the current object.

Comment: current object? what does it mean?

Comment: With c.addresses.new you only make an object in the memory (current object) to save it to the database you'll ned to do a = c.addresses.new, a.save.